# blitz++ and visual C++ 2013 namespace conflict with rank type

Tags: visual-c++, blitz++

I am trying to get the example project Blitz-Examples/array to compile i n Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.   We seem to get stuck on the following error: (This error does not exist in VS 2012)

> error C2955:’std::rank’ use of class template requires template
>   argument list.  File blitz/slice.h, line 57.

```
template<>
class ArraySectionInfo<Range> {
public:
    static const int isValidType = 1, rank = 1, isPick = 0;
};
```

The example program does not include the type_traits header file. Also in no place the example code imports `std::rank`.

Does any one encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the mailing list of Blitz++, you will note that other uses faced the same problem. [Here](http://sourceforge.net/p/blitz/mailman/message/31744812/) is a link to the discussion, as well as solution posted by Vince Virgilio. In the solution, you have to adjust the slice.h header file included with Boost++.