# Blitz does not work in vs 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, blitz++

I have a project I written in vs 2010. In this project blitz is used. But now when I open this project in 2013 and tried to run it. Some error says:

> error C2955: 'std::rank' : use of class template requires template argument list   ~~\blitz\indexexpr.h    69  1   MOM

So it appears in indexexpr.h

```
    static const int 
    numArrayOperands = 0, 
    numIndexPlaceholders = 1,
    rank = N+1;   //error here
```

How can I resovle it?
I see similar error from internet. But their error appear in slice.h.

Comment: Another approach may be to open it with vs 2010. But my current computer is only equipped with 2013. So how to open it in vs 2010?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [blitz++ and visual C++ 2013 namespace conflict with rank type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491385)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the discussion linked to by [Drew Dormann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181280/blitz-does-not-work-in-vs-2013#comment44731927_28181280) you should replace

```
static const int 
    numArrayOperands = 0, 
    numIndexPlaceholders = 1,
    rank = N+1;
```

with

```
static const int numArrayOperands = 0;
static const int numIndexPlaceholders = 1;
static const int rank = N+1;
```

Disclaimer: I don't know if this works.

Comment: Yes! This is just the right way. It works well! But you must correct other similar errors.